# Variables null inside onClick but not onCreate of Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclick, data-extraction

I am trying to pass some variables from an activity to a fragment and then back to an activity.  Inside the `onCreate` of the fragment, `getArguments()` is not null and I am able to get the variables.  But, inside the `onClick` of the fragment (which triggers going back to the activity), `getArguments()` and the variables I retrieved in the `onCreate` are null.

**In My Activity:**

```
  public void goToFragment() {
    MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
    // create new bundle and put extras
    Bundle myExtras = new Bundle();
    myExtras.putString("firstName", firstName);
    myExtras.putString("lastName", lastName);
    myExtras.putString("favoriteColor", favoriteColor);
    myFragment.setArguments(myExtras);        
    // start the fragment
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, myFragment.newInstance())
                        .add(myFragment, myExtras.toString())
                        .commit();
  }
```

**My Fragment:**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String favoriteColor;

    private Button myButton;

    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            firstName = MyFragment.this.getArguments().getString("firstName");
            lastName = MyFragment.this.getArguments().getString("lastName");
            favoriteColor = MyFragment.this.getArguments().getString("favoriteColor");
            Log.d(TAG, "Extras from activity page: firstName = " + firstName + ", lastName = " + lastName + ", favoriteColor = " + favoriteColor);
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "getArguments() != null");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.myButton);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: triggered...");

        // **ISSUE:** my variables are null here even though they were set in the `onCreate`
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: firstName = " + firstName);
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: lastName = " + lastName);
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: favoriteColor = " + favoriteColor);

        // Alternative attempt: get extras
        //if (MyFragment.this.getArguments() != null) {
        //    firstName = getArguments().getString("firstName");
        //    lastName = getArguments().getString("lastName");
        //    favoriteColor = getArguments().getString("favoriteColor");
        //    Log.d(TAG, "Extras getArguments(): firstName = " + firstName + ", lastName = " + lastName + ", favoriteColor = " + favoriteColor);
        //} else {
        //    Log.d(TAG, "getArguments() != null");
        //}

        // initiate intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("firstName", firstName);
        intent.putExtra("lastName", lastName);
        intent.putExtra("favoriteColor", favoriteColor);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    }
}
```

Alternative attempts:

- I also tried changing `firstName` to `MyFragment.this.firstName` in the `onClick`
- Thinking that the issue might be that the fragment's variables could not be accessed within the `onClick`, I also tried taking the code from the `onCreate` and putting it inside the `onClick` (so that the variables are set when the button is clicked, but `getArguments()` (and `MyFragment.this.getArguments()`) is null inside the `onClick` too

**Does anyone understand why my variables are null inside the `onClick` but not `onCreate` of Fragment (and how to prevent this issue)?**

Comment: Please paste the log  file, Thanks

Comment: replace this  `.replace(R.id.container, myFragment.newInstance())` with `.replace(R.id.container, myFragment)`

Comment: share newInstance() of your fragment

Comment: .add(myFragment, myExtras.toString()) remove this line

Comment: why the downvote?  As with any question, please explain if you're going to downvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, myFragment)
                    .commit();
```

instead of this

```
 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                     .replace(R.id.container, myFragment.newInstance())
                     .add(myFragment, myExtras.toString())
                     .commit();
```

Comment: This worked like a charm!  It makes a bit of sense that the old code as calling `newInstance` on `myFragment`, while this new way just passes the whole fragment that I've constructed (including the extras).  Although, I am still curious why the `add` method worked for the `onCreate` but not the `onClick`.  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome @Rbar happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

> NullPointerException is thrown when an application attempts to use an
>   object reference that has the null value.

Update your **`replace`** method. Remove **`.add`** method.

```
.replace(R.id.container, _fragmentOBJ)
```

**Structure**

> FragmentTransaction replace (int containerViewId, 
>                   Fragment fragment)

Then

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
firstName = bundle.getString("firstName","");
```

Answer (score 0):

I could see two issues in the code that is posted.

1. Why both `add()` and `replace()` are used. Choose any one depending on your requirement.
2. You have created an instance of `Fragment` using `new` keyword

   `MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();` and set the arguments.

But calling `myFragment.newInstance()` in `replace()`. Hoping (as the code not shared) that the `newInstance()` is creating another instance of the `Fragment` and no arguments set to that instance. This might be resulting in your null arguments in the fragment.